# how to change the content search web part query dynamically in share point 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, taxonomy, content-search-web-part

In my SP site documents or list items are getting tagged with some taxonomy value.

I have a SP Page, where I have added Content search web part and the result shows in search results web part on page load.

Now what I want is when I click on one of the taxonomy value from the taxonomy based top navigation, the search results web part should show results based on respected taxonomy value.

So, how can I dynamically change the CSWP query based on top navigation click?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I once had similar requirement, so I actually used `Search result` webpart, but you can check below code for `Content Search` webpart as well.
Code is somewhat different for `Content Search` webpart, which you can check by this good [article](http://sharepointificate.blogspot.com/2014/08/content-search-webpart-dynamic-filtering.html).

I had one site drop-down, list drop-down, keyword text-box and next to that search button which will search the result dynamically.

Below is the `jquery` code for on change event for site drop-down on content search that you can use:

```
  // Attach change event handler to Site dropdown
  $('#drpSites').change(function () {
        // Get selected product ID
        var sites = $(this).val();

        // Loop through Query Groups
        var groups = Srch.ScriptApplicationManager.get_current().queryGroups;

        $.each(groups, function () {
          // Look for query groups associated with a CSWP
          if (this.displays != null && this.displays.length > 0) {
            if (this.displays[0] instanceof Srch.ContentBySearch) {
              // Update and execute query
              var newQuery = 'contentType:Orders sites:' + prd;

              this.dataProvider.set_queryTemplate(newQuery);
              this.dataProvider.issueQuery();
            }
          }
        });
  });
```

So for your termset you can enter your query in `newQuery` variable to fetch data accordingly.

Hope this helps!